# Am I allowed to change XAMPP's distribution zip file?

Tags: apache, xampp

I'd like to give my users a shrinked package of Xampp (without MySQL and tomcat folders). That means that I'd like to take the original ZIP file (from sourceforge.net) and remove some unnecessary folders (but leave Apache folder since I need its web server). Am I allowed to do so? Am I allowed to give my users such an distribution kit?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for legal advice.

Answer (score -1):

> XAMPP is a very easy to install Apache Distribution for Linux,
>   Solaris, Windows, and Mac OS X. The package includes the Apache web
>   server, MySQL, PHP, Perl, a FTP server and phpMyAdmin.

Nothing is owned by the creators of the XAMPP installer, so the simple answer is: **Yes**, you can download and remove content from the .zip file and serve that.

[Visit](https://www.apachefriends.org/about.html) their homepage for further information.

XAMPP is published under [GNU License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), so you can basically modify XAMPP the way you want to, and then you need to publish it under GNU as well.

Comment: "Nothing is owned by the creators of the XAMPP installer" — They created the installer. They created the package. It's a derivative work, but they hold copyright on parts of it.

Comment: Read up on [GNU License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) @Quentin

Comment: _The licenses for most software and other practical works are designed to take away your freedom to share and change the works. By contrast, the GNU General Public License is intended to guarantee your freedom to share and change all versions of a program--to make sure it remains free software for all its users. We, the Free Software Foundation, use the GNU General Public License for most of our software; it applies also to any other work released this way by its authors. You can apply it to your programs, too._

Comment: Which means that you can modify it and redistribute it **but only if you meet the terms of the GPL**, it isn't public domain. If you read the page you link to in your answer, you'll notice that it also says *it is only the compilation of XAMPP that is published under GPL. Please check every single licence of the contained products to get an overview of what is, and what isn't, allowed*

Comment: And nothing in their licenses says that you can't remove another program from the XAMPP package.

Comment: Some do say such things as requiring that you make the source code as well as the installers available though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124729/discussion-between-anuga-and-quentin).